# Circles: addPeople for gmail accounts

Tags: php, google-api, google-plus, google-oauth, google-plus-domains

The [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) specifies a number of operations that can be done using Google Apps accounts for a domain. In PHP, these methods are

```
google_plus_circle_get
google_plus_people_add            
google_plus_message_send          
google_plus_message_read          
google_plus_group_post_send       
google_plus_group_post_read       
google_plus_page_post_send        
google_plus_page_post_read        
google_plus_timeline_post_send    
google_plus_timeline_post_read   
google_plus_post_share_send      
google_plus_post_share_read      
google_plus_post_like_send       
google_plus_post_like_read
```

Are there equivalent functions that are available if you are using a GMail account and not a Google Apps account?

Comment: The question was a bit unclear, but the gist of the question was there based on the tags. I've rewritten to make the question itself a bit more clear.

Comment: How to find a solution for below question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003042/how-to-pass-the-custom-title-description-and-image-to-google-plus-api-share-but

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. These functions are only available to Apps Domains and the accounts created for them.

The "regular" Google+ API is read-only and only works on fully public information. There are a number of [open issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/list) requesting these features, and you may wish to review the list and star those you're most interested in, giving detailed use cases where possible.